# Flutter change a "shared" widget as the route changes, like the navBar of facebook.com

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't know if I used correct terms in the title. I meant **share** by **being displayed in diffrent pages with the same state**, so that even if I *push* a new page, the “shared” widget will stay the same.

I'm trying to share the same widget across several pages, like the navigation bar of [facebook.com](https://facebook.com).

As I know, Navigator widget allows to build up a seperate route. I've attempted to use the widget here, and it works quite well.

```
...
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
  children: [
    Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: settings,
            builder: (context) => MainPage());
      },
      // observers: <RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>>[ routeObserver ],
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      child: BottomBarWithRecord(),
    )
  ],
));
...
```

To summarize the situation, there used to be only one root Navigator (I guess it's provided in MaterialApp, but anyway), and I added another Navigator in the route under a `Stack` (which always display `BottomBarWithRecord`).

This code works perfect as I expected, that `BottomBarWithRecord` stays the same even if I open a new page in that new Navigator. I can also open a new page without `BottomBarWithRecord` by pushing the page in the root Navigator: `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(smthsmth)`

However, I couldn't find a way to change BottomBarWithRecord() as the route changes, like the appbar of [facebook.com](https://facebook.com).

### What I've tried

#### Subscribe to route using navigator key

As I know, to define a navigator key, I have to write `final navigatorKey = GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState>(context);`. This doesn't seem to have addListener thing, so I couldn't find a solution here

#### Subscribe to route using navigator observer

It was quite complicated. Normally, a super complicated solutions works quite well, but it didn't. By putting `with RouteAware` after `class ClassName`, I could use some functions like `void didPush() {}` `didPop()` `didPushNext` to subscribe to the route. However, it was not actually "subscribing" to the route change; it was just checking if user opened this page / opened a new page from this page / ... , which would be complicated to deal with in my situation.

#### React.js?

When I learned a bit of js with React, I remember that this was done quite easily; I just had to put something like

```
...
const [appBarIndex, setAppBarIndex] = useState(0);
//0 --> highlight Home icon, 1 --> highlight Chats icon, 2 --> highlight nothing
...
window.addEventListener("locationChange", () => {
  //location is the thing like "/post/postID/..."
  if (window.location == "/chats") {
    setAppBarIndex(1);
  } else if (window.location == "/") {
    setAppBarIndex(0);
  } else {
    setAppBarIndex(2);
  }
})
```

Obviously I cannot use React in flutter, so I was finding for a similar easy way to do it on flutter.

### How can I make the shared `BottomBarWithRecord` widget change as the route changes?

Oh man it's already 2AM ahhhh
Thx for reading this till here, and I gotta go sleep rn
If I've mad e any typo, just ignore them

Comment: does the [bottom navigation bar widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) not solve your use case?

Comment: I don’t think so, cause I’m trying to display the same widget across pages, so that even if I **push** a new page, the shared widget stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a root widget from which you'll control what screen should be displayed and position the screen and the BottomBar accordingly. So instead of having a `Navigator()` and `BottomBar()` inside your `Stack`, you'll have `YourScreen()` and `BottomBar()`.

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: _buildScreen(screenIndex),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: BottomBar(
                screenIndex,
                onChange: (newIndex) {
                  setState(() {
                    screenIndex = newIndex;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

`BotttomBar` will use the `screenIndex` passed to it to do what you had in mind and highlight the selected item.

`_buildScreen` will display the corresponding screen based on `screenIndex` and you pass the `onChange` to your `BottomBar` so that it can update the screen if another item was selected. You won't be using `Navigator.of(context).push()` in this case unless you want to route to a screen without the `BottomBar`. Otherwise the `onChange` passed to `BottomBar` will be responsible for updating the index and building the new screen.

This is how you could go about it if you wanted to implement it yourself. This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) can do what you want as well. Here is a simple example:

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      const FirstScreen(),
      const SecondScreen(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
        title: ('First Screen'),
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
        title: ('Second Screen'),
      ),
    ];
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('First Screen'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('Second Screen'),
    );
  }
}
```